# Mysql query with IF

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement

I have two tables

Users

```
  Id                user         grade    access_level
  1                Alice           1            1
  2               Charles          3            3
  3                 Ben            2            2
```

Class

```
  Id                name         grade
  1               biology          1
  2                math            2
  3              geography         2
```

I can read `$username = $_SESSION['MM_Username']` and I want to select for each logged user a list of classes depending on their access_level. For access_level => 3 the user can see all the classes, for access_level < 3 user can see only classes with the same grade with his/hers. So:
For Charles, with access_level=3, I want this result

```
  Id                name         grade
  1               biology          1
  2                math            2
  3              geography         2
```

For Alice, with access_level=1 and grade = 1, I want this result

```
  Id                name         grade
  1               biology          1
```

And for Ben, with access_level=2 and grade = 2, I want this result

```
  Id                name         grade
  1                math            2
  2              geography         2
```

## Added from the comment

They have the access_levels based on their position in school. Let's say that Charles is a professor and Alice and Ben are students. Students can see only their classes, but the teacher can see everything.

Comment: And waht's your question now? Whats access_level for if you only use grade afterwards to compare?

Comment: The question is: how to query something if access_level=1 and something else if access_level=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a INNER JOIN with OR:

```
SELECT Class.*
FROM
  Class INNER JOIN Users
  ON Class.grade = Users.grade
     OR Users.access_level>=3
WHERE
  User='username';
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b095b/3).

Comment: So, the query MUST read from Users (based on variable $username) two data = access_level and grade. Than query the table Class like this: if access_level is >= 3 than take ALL data, if access_level<3 than take data where Users.grade = Class.grade

Comment: @MugurUngureanu the query has to read only the username, the access_level is fixed, if >=3 take all data, otherwise take only data where Class.grade = Users.grade

Comment: Yes. The application has to give the teacher possibility to group his students (based on grade) and to assign each group to some classes. Each group have to see only their assigned classes.

Comment: I will try it in a few moments. And I will be back to you!

Comment: for the sample I gave it is working. For the real problem it is not working, yet! :) But is somewhere a problem related with the way I read and use the variables. Thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what are you going to achieve, According to my understanding you can do something like this below.

```
SELECT u.user,c.name 
FROM user AS u INNER JOIN class AS c ON u.grade = c.grade
WHERE u.access_level = 1 AND u.grade = 1

SELECT u.user,c.name 
FROM user AS u INNER JOIN class AS c ON u.grade = c.grade
WHERE u.access_level = 2 AND u.grade = 2

SELECT u.user,c.name 
FROM users AS u INNER JOIN class AS c ON u.grade = c.grade
WHERE u.grade != 3
```

Comment: If access_level=3 I want to have all class, if access_level<3 I want to select only class where u.grade = c.grade.

Comment: change the access levels as you need

Comment: They have the access_levels based on their position in school. Let's say that Charles is a professor and Alice and Ben are students. Students can see only their classes, but the teacher can see everything.

Comment: see the 3 queries. they give you exactly what you need

Comment: Yes, but only for this sample. If I will add more users and grades....So, the query MUST read from Users (based on variable $username) two data = access_level and grade. Than query the table Class like this: if access_level is >= 3 than take ALL data, if access_level<3 than take data where Users.grade = Class.grade

Comment: You will have to use a if statement for that. Make the query dynamic replace 1,2,3 with variables

Comment: Yes, this is an ideea. In this moment I am not sure how many access_level I will finally have...

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM Users as U, Class as C
WHERE U.user = $username
AND U.access_level>=C.grade
```

Comment: The numbers are only for sample. There are many users any many classes. I need to have a query that select specific grade not a relation based on >=

Comment: I am thinking like this: Teacher (Charles) with access_level=3 can see everything, and students with access_level < 3 can see only their class, based on their grade.